# Validate Joi - all array elements have the same nested value

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, validation, joi

I want to use Joi to validate the incoming JSON request object, so that each array element has the same value at the path `.runs[].results.type`. If there's a single element that sticks out, the validation should fail. Something like the opposite of [`array.unique`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.1#arrayuniquecomparator-options) over `.results.type` inside `.runs[]`.

Imagine the following JSONs as valid inputs:

```js
{
  runs: [
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'left' }, meta: { createdBy: 3 } },
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'right' }, meta: { createdBy: 1 } }
  ]
}
```

And this should throw a validation error:

```js
{
  runs: [
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'left' }, meta: { createdBy: 3 } },
    { results: { type: 'B', side: 'right' }, meta: { createdBy: 1 } }
  ]
}
```

I tried writing a Joi schema like:

```js
...
  runs: Joi.array()
    .min(1)
    .items(
      Joi.object()
        .unknown()
        .keys({
          results: Joi.object()
            .keys({
              type: Joi.string()
                .allow('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
                .valid(Joi.ref('....', { in: true, adjust: runs => runs.map(run => run.results.type) }))
                .required(),
              side: Joi.string().allow('left', 'right')
            })
        })
    )
...
```

But this doesn't work (I think it ends up in circular reference). Also, even if it were to run successfully, I am not sure if it would actually break the validation in case two diff types `A` and `B` are provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a kind of elegant solution without using custom functions, although that would be a pretty good way to solve this!

```js
Joi.object().keys({
  runs: Joi.array().items(
    Joi.object().keys({
      results: Joi.object().keys({
        type: Joi.string().valid(
          Joi.ref('....0.results.type')
        ).required() 
      })
    })
  ).has(
    Joi.object().keys({ 
      results: Joi.object().keys({
        type: Joi.valid('A', 'B', 'C', 'D').required()
      })
    }))
  })
```

It's based on first determining that all `runs[]` elements have the same value of `.results.type`, and then asserting that the `runs` array `.has()` at least one element that has `.results.type` from `{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}`.

Interesting thing I learned is that in Joi, the array elements are indexed with dots in `.ref()`, like `$runs.0.results`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) o [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function, that returns if there is at least **some** element that accomplish a condition, or if **every** element accomplish a condition:

**1)** Using `.some()`:

```js
const object1 = {
  runs: [
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'left' }, meta: { createdBy: 3 } },
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'right' }, meta: { createdBy: 1 } }
  ]};

const object2 = {
runs: [
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'left' }, meta: { createdBy: 3 } },
    { results: { type: 'B', side: 'right' }, meta: { createdBy: 1 } }
  ]};
  
let result1 = object1.runs.some(e => e.results.type !== 'A');

console.log(result1);   // false

let result2 = object2.runs.some(e => e.results.type !== 'A');

console.log(result2);   // true
```

**2)** Using `.every()`:

```js
const object1 = {
  runs: [
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'left' }, meta: { createdBy: 3 } },
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'right' }, meta: { createdBy: 1 } }
  ]};

const object2 = {
runs: [
    { results: { type: 'A', side: 'left' }, meta: { createdBy: 3 } },
    { results: { type: 'B', side: 'right' }, meta: { createdBy: 1 } }
  ]};
  
let result1 = object1.runs.every(e => e.results.type === 'A');

console.log(result1);   // true

let result2 = object2.runs.every(e => e.results.type === 'A');

console.log(result2);   // false
```

- In case you don´t know the target value (in this case **'A'**) just take the first type value -> `runs[0].results.type` and replace the 'A' with it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a valid solution for javascript/typescript, however I'm looking for a specific way on how to write a Joi schema.

Additionally, the solutions you provided are good for the case when there's only two possible types, but not when there's more of them.

Comment: @maricn You can mix javascript with Joi using [a custom Joi validation](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anycustommethod-description)